# Haskell in append few list together

Tags: haskell

I want to the value of one element in a List , So I did the

```
changePoint :: (Int,Int) -> [[[Char]]] -> [[Char]]

changePoint (x,y) maze = let 

          linelement = maze !! (y-1) 

-- value ["X"," "," ",...," ","X"]

          rowelement = chunksOf 1 $ head linelement 
-- type:[[a]]; value ["X"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","X"]

          l = length rowelement
          list = take (x-1) rowelement

--          in take (x-1) rowelement  -- ["X"]  

           in take (x-1) rowelement ++ (["."] : (drop (x) rowelement))
```

I want to append the list  "take (x-1) rowelement" and "["."]" and "drop (x) rowelement",  the type of list will be  [[a]]

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
  In the expression: "."
  In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘["."]’
  In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
    ‘(["."] : (drop (x) rowelement))’ Failed, modules loaded: none.

x = 2 .
```

I know the problem is "["."]",but I really don't how to fix it .

The true return should be `["X","."," "," ",..,"X" ]`

Answer (score 1):

In GHCI, you can use `:t somefunction` to get the type of `somefunction`.

Here, the problem is with `(:)`, lets see what GHCI tells us.

```
Prelude λ> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So `(:)` takes an `a`, a list of `a`s and returns a new list. Specialized for the use case at hand, `(:)` has type `[Char] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]` (because `a = [Char]`). But `["."]` has type `[[Char]]`, so it does not match what's expected for `(:)`.

Now, if you use `take (x-1) rowelement ++ ("." : (drop (x) rowelement))` (note the missing `[]` around `"."`), the function should compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
(take (x-1) rowelement) ++ ["."] ++ (drop x rowelement)
```

Or

```
(take (x-1) rowelement) ++ ("." : (drop x rowelement))
```

The `[` and `]` are not necessary

Comment: `[` `]` are actually necessary in the first example.